# Is there something special about wget?

Tags: bash

I was trying to download this web page  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Coimbatore+&sensor=true (Google maps api) using bash command wget. But the response I got for this was a page that informed me that the the request was denied. I tried to download the same using Python urllib functions, which was a success. So what is so special about wget? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash has a special meaning for the **&** character.  You either need to proceed it with a backslash ( **\** ) or wrap the entire URL in single quotes ( **'** ).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the special chars are interpreted by bash (`?` for instance, and ̀ &` that makes the process in background).
Just wrap it arround simple quotes, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine this is because of [*robots.txt*](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

You could tweak the UserAgent to (potentially) get past

If you have permission (!!!) of the website owner, you could ignore robots.txt by passing `-erobots=off` to wget, so:

```
wget -erobots=off \
    'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Coimbatore+&sensor=true'
```